# Azure Bot gets stuck on login card after successful login using OAuth2 Generic Provider

Tags: azure, botframework

Starting from the following sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

Replaced the authentication provider with an OAuth2 generic provider.

When clicking on the login button, the login windows pops up and user is able to authenticate successfully. However, when it gets back to main window, the "You are now logged in" response is not obtained.

When testing on the Azure portal, token is successfully obtained.

Kindly advise.

Thanks

Comment: When you say that the user is able to authenticate successfully in the login window, does it show the validation code? Also, there might be issues with the Emulator. What version of emulator are you using?

Comment: 4.2.1 --> Checked the "Use the sign in verification code for OAuthCards" as per your unedited comment, and now everything is working. May need to update documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication

Comment: Glad that it helped. If you look at the README.md for the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph#testing-the-bot-using-bot-framework-emulator), it specifies that you need to enable the option.

Comment: Found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot-authentication-msgraph sample uses the bot authentication capabilities of Azure Bot Service, providing features to make it easier to develop a bot that authenticates users to various identity providers such as Azure AD (Azure Active Directory), GitHub, Uber, and so on. While testing the sample on the emulator, enable '**Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards**' in the Bot Framework Emulator Settings and save, to receive the magic code.